# How to Fix Except Error in Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to execute a python script from Linux but I'm keep getting this error on the except line. Can someone figure this out?

```
$ python pygeo_ip.py

def search(self):


    message = ''
result_count = 0
gip = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoLIteCity.dat')
ip = self.ip_textbox.text()
try:
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(str(ip))
    message = "Host: %s Is Currently Available" % (str(ip))
except socket.error, e:
    message = "Host: %s Is Currently Unavailable" % (key, val)
result_count += 1
msg_box("SeArCh CoMpLeTe", "%d REsults Were Found For %s"
% (result_count, str(ip))
except Exception, e:   <------- Error
msg_box("", str(e))
msg_box("Search Complete", "No Results Were Found For %s" % (str(ip))
return
```

Error:

```
File "pygeo_ip.py", line 142
    except Exception, e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: As the error says, the syntax is incorrect. Check out [the "Handling Exceptions" section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the documentation.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade autopep8` , then `autopep8 -i pygeo_ip.py`

Comment: can you fix your formatting?
It looks like your error is the second `except` isn't at the same level as the `try` and `except socket.error` but I'm unable to tell unless you clean up your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure (without having tested anything) your problem is having missed the last close bracket

Line should read:

```
msg_box("SeArCh CoMpLeTe", "%d REsults Were Found For %s" % (result_count, str(ip)) )
```